# Website that identifies different sentence types

Tags: discussion

I am trying to find a website that I used a while ago that identified different sentence types. You paste the text into the text box and then through a selection of buttons on the right, you could highlight the different sentence types in different colours. For example, all the complex sentences would be identified in red. Click on the simple sentence button and that would highlight all the simple sentences in yellow etc..

The website also allowed you to do this for the parts of the speech.

However I can not find this website again. I have looked through google and seen similar sites, like Grammarly, Hemmingway app, Parts-of-speech.Info but I still want to find the one I used before.

It was free to use and I think it was called coffee something...? Any help will be great.

Comment: Sounds like a question for ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sounds like a proofreading programme or grammar checker... https://typely.com/  and also https://www.sodacoffee.com/tools/grammar-checker/ SodaCoffee

Comment: In this regard, there used to be a site that diagrammed sentences. You would type in the sentence, and it would be diagrammed and each component labeled. I can still get to that site on an old computer that uses Windows 7, but on my current Windows 10 system, going to the same URL takes me to a site where the application has to be purchased, and what the purchaser gets (from comments) is worthless. Apparently, the same URL produces different results depending on the location of your server (country), etc.